# Better understanding regular functions on a Projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hi guys I was just looking an example from class that was left as obvious, but it is not so obvious to me.

$W= V(x_1x_4-x_2x_3)= $ where $I(W)= \langle x_1x_4-x_2x_3 \rangle$ so we just picked an regular function in the example the function was $\phi = \frac{x_1}{x_2}$ then we saied that this is the same as $\phi = \frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{x_3}{x_4}$ Which I am good with but then we said that it turns out $\phi =\frac{x_1u-x_3h}{x_2u-x_4h}$
This is where I am confused I do not see how that is true.

Comment: One small detail - $\phi$ is regular only on a subset of $W$.  What are $u$ and $h$?  They can be solved for with linear algebra.

Comment: yes $\phi$ is regular only on W. I have no Idea about the u and h and I am sorry about that... that is why I am so confused.